# How to work out which variable has the most characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-length

How to work out which variable has the most characters.

For example :

```
var one = "qwert";
var two = "qwertyu"
var three ="qwertyuiop";
```

How to work out which variable has the most character.

First thing I am doing is counting the number of characters in each string.

```
var onelength = one.length;
var twolength = two.length;
var threelength = three.length;
```

The part I am struggling on is javascript to work out which of the above lengths has the most characters.

Comment: Well, start with two strings. Can you work it out for those?

Comment: Please clarify what you are expecting as the end result - ie if you want the max length `10`, the longest value `qwertyuip` or, as you've asked, the variable `three`.

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no way to do this in Javascript (nor indeed in most languages).

What you're asking for is a kind of [*reflection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Examples). Conceptually, a function `nameOfVariable` that takes a variable and gives you it's string name in return:

```
nameOfVariable(one): 'one'
```

Not possible.

The answers above are attempts to work around that.  Ultimately in real code this would be structured not as a bag of variables but as an object (which is kinda like a bag of variables, except you can recover the names)

```js
const strings = {
  one: 'abcde',
  two: 'abcdef',
  three: 'abcd',
};
  
  
// Return key in object corresponding to longest string, 
// or null if object is empty.
const longest_string = strings => {
  let max = null;
  for (let name in strings) {
    if (max === null || strings[name].length > strings[max].length) {
      max = name;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(longest_string(strings));
```

Comment: I like this. Nice clean code. It also doesn't cope well with the largest two strings being equally long.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It will return the first name encountered, which is fine in the absence of actual specs on how to handle ties.

Comment: I agree. This answer is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
[one,two,three].reduce((a,c) => a.length>c.length? a:c,'');
```

```js
var one = "qwert";
var two = "qwertyu";
var three ="qwertyuiop";

let r= [one,two,three].reduce((a,c) => a.length>c.length? a:c,'');

let v= Object.entries({one,two,three}).reduce((a,c) => a[1].length>c[1].length ? a:c,['','']);

console.log('longest variable:', v[0], '=', r);
```

Comment: Nice succinct code (and even more succinct explanation...) but which variable is the longest?  (TBH, I'm not sure that question makes sense...but it's what was asked)

Comment: That's it. It is rather complex though, for something so simple. It also doesn't deal well with the situation where to two largest strings are equally long. Not that I want you to solve that riddle, that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var words=['ape','parrot','elephant'];

console.log( longestWord( words ) );

function longestWord( words ){
 var longest = '';
 words.forEach(function(element){
   if(longest.length < element.length)
     longest = element;
 });
 return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JQuery for this. If you save the strings in an array:

```
const a = ["qwert","qwertadf","qwertfasdf"]
```

you can use this (using ES2015 features):

```
let max_length = Math.max(...a.map(e=>e.length))
```

If you want to know the greater element, you can use this:

```
a.findIndex(e => e.length === ml)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Math.max();`

Example:

```
Math.max(onelength, twolength, threelength);
```

This will return the highest value.

Comment: So, which variable is the longest? One, two or three? Does this answer that question?

Comment: I believe what @KIKOSoftware is saying is: using `Math.max` in this way will tell you the longest value (`10`) - but it won't tell you which of the variables `var one,two,three` is the longest.  It may be that OP just needs the max length, but that's not what they've explicitly asked.